# inner join with codeigniter duplicating results

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have the following code and I'm trying to get information based on one order number from about 4 different tables. I am using codeigniter, and with the following code I get a duplicate of the same record. Basically two rows are displayed when only one truly exists in the database.

```
function get_orders($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('Orders');
    $this->db->join('Order_Options', 'Orders.orderNumber = Order_Options.orderNumber');
    $this->db->join('Order_Products', 'Orders.orderNumber = Order_Products.orderNumber');
    $this->db->join('Order_Status', 'Orders.order_status = Order_Status.id');
    $this->db->where(array('user_id' => $user_id));

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I got this code from the codeigniters online user manual. The only line I added myself was the `where` and the `return` line.

Comment: how to solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `Debug` enable **[PROFILER](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html)** in your controller's constructor.

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

This will display all details below your `VIEW` including the `queries` executed.Use that query in phpmyadmin and debug.

Comment: I did what you said in the phpmyadmin and I removed the first join in my code and retrieved only one result with all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this tool, but this should return a separate record for each product in the order. (Or each option. Those look like many-to-many connection tables. I assume status IDs are unique, so that's probably not it.)

What I would do to debug is start simplifying the query, and then I could see which part causes the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
function get_orders($user_id)
    {
        $query=$this->db->select('*');
        ->distinct()
        ->from('Orders');
        ->join('Order_Options', 'Orders.orderNumber = Order_Options.orderNumber');
        ->join('Order_Products', 'Orders.orderNumber = Order_Products.orderNumber');
        ->join('Order_Status', 'Orders.order_status = Order_Status.id');
        ->where(array('user_id' => $user_id));
        ->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```